# showing Undefined index when insert data into database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> Notice: Undefined index: postId in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax-complete\save_post.php on line 4 
>   Notice: Undefined index: postTitle in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax-complete\save_post.php on line 8 
>   Notice: Undefined index: postDescription in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax-complete\save_post.php on line 8

```
    <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax_complete");

        if($_POST["postId"] != ''){
            $sql = "UPDATE tbl_post SET post_title ='".$_POST['postTitle']."', post_description = '".$_POST['postDescription']."' WHERE id ='".$_POST['postId']."'" ;
            mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        }else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_post (post_title,post_description,post_status) VALUES('".$_POST['postTitle']."','".$_POST['postDescription']."','draft')";
            mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            echo mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        }
    ?>
```

HTML CODE IS GIVEN BELOW

```
<h3>Auto save data </h3> 
        <div class="form-group">    
           <lable>Post Title</lable>
           <input type="text" name="post_title" id="post_title" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">    
           <lable>Post Description</lable>
           <input type="text" name="post_description" id="post_description" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">    
           <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div id="autosave"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function autosave(){
                var post_title = $('#post_title').val();
                var post_description = $('#post_description').val();
                var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
                if(post_title != '' && post_description != '')
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"save_post.php",
                        method:"POST",
                        data:{postTitle:post_title,postDescription:post_description,postId:post_id},
                        dataType:"text",
                        success:function(data){
                            if(data != ''){
                                $('#post_id').val(data);
                            }
                            $('#autosave').text('post save in DB');
                            setInterval(function(){
                                $('#autosave').text('');
                            },2000);
                        } 
                    });
                }
            }
            setInterval(function(){
                autosave();
            },10000);

        });
    </script>
    <script>
```

Comment: Can you post your form code too? `$_POST` isn't defined

Comment: i am sending data using ajax and its showin on that page if i m using Print_r($_POST);exitl

Comment: Please also provide your html form code...

Comment: Provide the JS. This is open to SQL injections, use parameterized queries. Also if using `mysqli` why tag `pdo`?

Comment: these are seprate pate

Comment: @ApurvaKinkar If it's not showing any error but not inserted it could be the structure of your table, can you include it.

Comment: it is showing error in php post_title and post_description is undefine index

Comment: @ApurvaKinkar can you `var_dump($_POST);` see if the `$_POST` data is been submitted

Comment: it is not submitted it show error in php post_title and post_description is undefine index

Comment: @ApurvaKinkar can you include your table structure. that could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

When the page is loaded in the browser, the way your code is structured it's evaluating `if($_POST["postId"] != '')`; but since it's a simple page load there is no `$_POST` array and hence the warnings. Add an additional check for $_POST, so that that entire block of code is skipped during normal page load.

```
if($_POST) {
    if($_POST["postId"] != ''){
            $sql = "UPDATE tbl_post SET post_title ='".$_POST['postTitle']."', post_description = '".$_POST['postDescription']."' WHERE id ='".$_POST['postId']."'" ;
            mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        }else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_post (post_title,post_description,post_status) VALUES('".$_POST['postTitle']."','".$_POST['postDescription']."','draft')";
            mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            echo mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please make your code more robust as suggested by @chris85. Your code is open to SQL injection. You should never trust post data and send directly to your DB. Use prepared statements.

Comment: its not showing error but data can not inserted into database

Comment: @ApurvaKinkar your `its working` and `not inserted into database` are contradicting. If your values contain a quote this will fail. You should check the status of `mysqli_query` and preferably use parameterized queries to avoid previously noted issue.

Comment: echo mysqli_insert_id($conn); showing 0 and data can not insert

Comment: @ApurvaKinkar the error reporting say `data can not insert`? I don't think I've ever seen such a return..

Comment: its showing in echo 0 and data can not inserted and after that call next ajax call

Comment: @ApurvaKinkar there maybe many reasons why data is not inserted in DB. Issues can range from DB connection, to malformed SQL or even mismatched data types. Please try to debug and print the INSERT SQL.

Comment: I'm going to leave this with @sm1979 but `data can not inserted` is not a return `mysqli` would return. Use error reporting effectively, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

In you PHP script you should use "post_id", "post_title and "post_description". Dash is used in front-end (name attribute of input tags), so you need to use the same in $POST.

Comment: This is incorrect. It is going through AJAX. `data:{postTitle:post_title,postDescription:post_description,postId:post_id}`